# Список превращается в слайдер на определённо расширении

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Всем хай, у меня очень актуальный вопрос.
Вот есть список блоков, и на каком-то расширении он превращается в слайдер.
Как это правильно сделать на swiper.js? Надоело уже всякие костыли юзать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const resizeSwiper = function resizeSwiper() {
    let swiperDom = document.querySelector('.spheres__content')
    let swiperStyle = document.querySelector('.main-page__spheres')
    if(document.body.clientWidth <= 550) {
        swiperDom.querySelector('.spheres__row').classList.add('swiper-wrapper')
        swiperDom.querySelectorAll('.spheres__column').forEach(item => {
            item.classList.add('swiper-slide')
        })
        new Swiper('.spheres__content', {})
        swiperStyle.classList.add('swiper-on')
        swiperStyle.classList.remove('swiper-off')
    } else {
        const swiper = new Swiper('.spheres__content', {})
        swiper.destroy(true,true)
        swiperDom.querySelector('.spheres__row').classList.remove('swiper-wrapper')
        swiperDom.querySelectorAll('.spheres__column').forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('swiper-slide')
        })
        swiperStyle.classList.add('swiper-off')
        swiperStyle.classList.remove('swiper-on')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно отслеживать ширину экрана, и на нужной вам ширине запускать инициализацию слайдера:

```
const width  = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
document.body.clientWidth;

if(width >= 720) {
    ... код инициализации слайдера
}
```